# Pass dynamic data to Internet Explorer - Create multiple logins

Tags: vba, excel

I want to automate Internet Explorer with macro in Excel.
I was able to do that with hard coded data. I want to copy data from another Sheet.

Example:- I want to create multiple logins in example.com website copying user name in Sheet.

My code in Excel:-

```
    Sub Submit()
        Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIE.Top = 0
        objIE.Left = 0
        objIE.Width = 800
        objIE.Height = 600
        objIE.AddressBar = 0
        objIE.StatusBar = 0
        objIE.Toolbar = 0
        objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation

        objIE.Navigate ("http://example.com")

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

        pageSource = objIE.Document.body.Outerhtml
        objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName").Value = "xyz"
        objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").Value = "123"
        objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit1").Click
    End Sub
```

Data in Excel

```
+------+---------------+
| User |    Password   |
+------+---------------+
| ABC  | 123           |
| XYZ  | 456           |
| XCZ  | 777           |
+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `User` and `Password` as paremeters for `Submit` sub.

```
Sub Submit(User as string, Password as string)
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.AddressBar = 0
    objIE.StatusBar = 0
    objIE.Toolbar = 0
    objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation

    objIE.Navigate ("http://example.com")

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

    pageSource = objIE.Document.body.Outerhtml
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName").Value = User 
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").Value = Password
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit1").Click
End Sub
```

Call this sub in another sub.

```
   Sub Login()
   dim strUser as string
   dim strPassword as string
   dim intLastRow  as integer
   dim intRow  as integer

       intLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       For intRow = 2 to intLastRow 
           strUser = Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(intRow, 1).value
           strPassword = Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(intRow, 2).value       
           call Submit(strUser, strPassword)
       Next intRow
   End Sub
```

This may work.